# Fresh install of Windows keeps freezing

Tags: freeze

I got a computer from a friend who said he got some viruses and that he didn't have the time to fix it. I decided to just reformat and do a fresh install. Windows 7 installed fine but after booting in, it would freeze every twenty minutes or so and I would have to reboot.

I thought maybe I messed up installing something so I reinstalled it. Still froze. I put in a Debian LiveCD I had lying around and that worked fine. Booted back into Win7, but safe mode this time, and that worked fine as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run a memory test overnight and see if it picks up any hardware problems.

Comment: I actually ran memtest and it would stop responding, though the cursor still blinks.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian distribution comes with most of the necessary device drivers already included in the installation ISO file. Device drivers that are not included in the installation ISO file, such as the drivers for Nvidia and AMD Radeon graphics cards, can be easily installed from the Debian repositories. The Synaptic package manager, which is installed by default in Debian, can be used to easily search for and install these drivers.

In Windows, on the other hand, many of the device drivers for the motherboard, graphics card, etc. need to be installed from CD/DVDs that are packaged with the devices. If you are missing any of these device drivers, it can cause performance issues such as freezing.

If the Windows device driver for an Nvidia or AMD graphics card is missing, you should find out the model number of your graphics card, and then search the internet to find out the approximate Nvidia or AMD version number of the graphics card driver. Download the closest matching version number graphics card driver that you can find from the AMD or Nvidia website. Also make sure that you match your OS's architecture, either 32-bit or 64-bit. The graphics card driver should install and run OK in Windows.

Comment: I think I installed drivers for everything.